# How to convert json file to xml (full-conversion) in mule-studio

Tags: xml, json, mule-studio

I am very new to Mulestudio.

I have a JSON file which am trying to convert it into XML.

JSON File:

```
{
  "contact" : [ {
    "name" : "harrison, john (emp)",
    "phone" : "1111 1111"
  }, {
    "name" : "doe, jane (emp)",
    "phone" : "2222 2222"
  }, {
    "name" : "No Phone, Harry (emp)",
    "phone" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "Larson, Larry (mgr)",
    "phone" : "4444 4444"
  }, {
    "name" : "Johnson, John (mgr)",
    "phone" : "6666 6666"
  } ]
}
```

Mulestudio flow:

```
 <file:connector name="input" autoDelete="false" doc:name="input"/>

    <file:connector name="output" doc:name="output"/>
    <flow name="FileEndpointFlow1" doc:name="FileEndpointFlow1">

        <file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="input"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="input" path="C:\testmule1" pollingFrequency="100000"/>
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json" />

        <json:is-json-filter />

        <json:json-to-xml-transformer  doc:name="JSON to xml"/>

        <file:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="output" path="C:\output"/>

    </flow>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><contact><name>harrison, john (emp)</name><phone>1111 1111</phone></contact>
```

The input JSON file is partially converted to XML. Can someone help me how to convert entire JSON file to XML file.

Comment: This link will give the explanation 
please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083725/why-is-the-mule-json-to-xml-transformer-only-picking-up-the-first-element